# What should be the CMakeLists.txt organization?

Tags: c++, cmake

This is my directory structure, and below are my CMakeLists.txt files in each directory.

```
app
    include
       inc.hpp
    lib
       question.cpp
       answer.cpp
       CMakeLists.txt
    src
       answer.cpp
       CMakeLists.txt
    CMakeLists.txt
```

app/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR)

project(hg2g_example LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(lib)
```

app/src/CMakeLists.txt (contents)

```
include_directories(../include)

add_executable(answer answer.cpp)

target_link_libraries(answer liber)

install(TARGETS answer DESTINATION bin)
```

app/lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(lib_headers ../include/inc.hpp
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/inc.hpp")
set(lib_sources answer.cpp question.cpp)

add_library(liber ${lib_sources} ${lib_headers})

target_include_directories(liber PUBLIC
    include
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include")

install(TARGETS liber DESTINATION lib)

install(FILES ${lib_headers} DESTINATION include)
```

inc.hpp has declarations of two functions, one of which is defined in lib/question.cpp and the other in lib/answer.cpp, src/answer.cpp further calls these functions.

I am unable to understand how to use CMake to produce this kind of file structure, I'm fine with working with CMake as long as all files are in the same folder.

Can someone help me understand how does this work with multiple directories that serve different purposes?

Edit: Resolved

Comment: [Always use the most recent CMake version](https://alexreinking.com/blog/how-to-use-cmake-without-the-agonizing-pain-part-1.html)

Comment: So, you have C++ headers and sources, and have `CMakeLists.txt` which organizes them. What is a **problem**? Does the code (`CMakeLists.txt`) works as expected? If not, please state (in the question post) what is going wrong. Currently it is unclear what help do you want from us.

Comment: @Tsyvarev hey, sorry, I totally missed that, I was getting missing sources, however, I understood my mistake on one of the lines.

Comment: I strongly recommend putting public headers in a (file system) subdirectory of the directory responsible for creating the target. In this case it may not be problematic, but if you ever want to restructure the file structure by e.g. moving `app/lib` to `app/foo/bar/lib` you need to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` in addition to changing the `add_subdirectory` command which wouldn't be necessary, if the headers were inside the dir. Specifying a public include dir for the target would take care of making the includes available...